# SQL Server 2005: how to subtract 6 month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime, date, datediff

I have a date, suppose today date

```
declare @d datetime
set @d = '20101014'
```

I need

```
select @d - <six month>
```

where  is the real number of days that contains last six month, beginning from @d.

Comment: Sorry but your question is a little unclear; are you asking for the date less 6 months or the date 6 months ago?

Comment: Or the number of days since the date 6 months ago?

Comment: how many days = now - 6 month ago

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

```
select DATEADD(month, -6, @d)
```

**EDIT**: if you need the number of days up to 6 months ago you can use [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

```
select DATEDIFF(day, @d, DATEADD(month, -6, @d))
```

Comment: In this way i'll get date, but i need number of days

Answer (score 1):

Also check this up (developing this theme):

i need to choose the algorythm depending on the condition - if there are as many days between two dates as in 6 month (ago from the last date).

I did it in this way:

```
    case
      when
        DATEDIFF(day, DATEADD(month, -6, @pDateEnd), @pDateEnd)
        >
        DATEDIFF(day, @pDateBegin, @pDateEnd)
      then 'there is no 6-month difference between two dates'
      else 'there is 6-month difference ore more between two dates'
    end
```