# get todays date with last 6 months back

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2005

I want the exact date as `22/06/2015` from the query

whose `Joining date` should be **exact**

> 22/06/2015

which is exact `6 months` back from todays date

I tried like below

```
 Select date_of_joining,*  from emp_mst Where  Dt_Of_Join >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, getdate())), 0)
```

but it didn't worked.

what is the exact query for that ?

I am using `SQL- server- 2005`

Comment: okay what the result you got for the above query @coder

Comment: @mohan111: it was displaying me `93` rows but in actually it is just `5` rows

Comment: You really should clarify your question and not let the community spend a lot of time chasing an answer to a question of which you are not even certain.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I am really sorry for my confusing question. I moved a bit ahead, Your query was giving me result as `Jun 22 2015  1:15PM` I want it as `22/06/2015` what shd I do ?

Comment: You have your answer below.  Please learn how to ask a good question in the future.

Comment: Yeah, I got the answer. many a thanks for your answer too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the EXACT joining date ( /date_of_joining.... /Dt_Of_Join)
what about

```
select distinct employee.name from emp_mst where date_of_joining = DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())
```

or if you want the actual date returned in a different format:

```
 CONVERT(Date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()), 103)
```

which is applicable if you select this field

Comment: can you show the actual code? or explain what exactly do you have and want

Comment: did you change the employee.name field to the proper field name?

Comment: try select distinct employee.name from emp_mst where date_of_joining = cast (DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()) as Date)   following Mayank P. lead..

Comment: the date is coming exact as `Jun 22 2015` but i want it as `22/06/2015` so what shd I do ?

Comment: thats a different question..... you stated you only want the employee name so why bother with date format??  :)  in any case, use CONVERT(Date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()), 103) where 103 is the format code that (I think) you want

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a SQL Server guru, but I found easy answers everywhere for this.

Try this link to another post which explains this exact question [SQL Server 2005: how to subtract 6 month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932947/sql-server-2005-how-to-subtract-6-month)

You refer to the word **"exact"** date, so you don't need the datediff section, you can just subtract 6 months from the current date using "dateadd" which will give you a precise date. Just remember to correctly type cast else you will have to be accurate to the millisecond.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  employee_name
FROM emp_mst
WHERE Dt_Of_Join = Cast(DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()) As Date)
ORDER BY Dt_Of_Join DESC
```

I think he just need to know how to remove time from date

Answer (score 0):

Note that you need to handle time part effectively

```
Select *  from emp_mst 
Where  
Dt_Of_Join >= dateadd(month,-6,dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),0) 
and 
Dt_Of_Join < dateadd(month,-6,dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want previous 6 month date so use `dateadd()` and for your date formate `DD/MM/YYYY`  you should try to `convert(varchar(10),date,101)`.

```
Select date_of_joining,*  from emp_mst Where
Dt_Of_Join=convert(varchar(10),dateadd(month,-6,getdate()),101)
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations.