# How do I set EndDate by 3 months

Tags: t-sql

I am struggling to accomplish set date if value is entered. So I wondering if someone could advise me how to do this. This is what I have done...

```
Declare 
@StartDate DateTime,
@EndDate DateTime,
@Discount Varchar

If @Discount = 'Test123'
Begin
 UPDATE tblName SET EndDate = case 
 When StartDate > dateadd(month,-3,getdate())  
End
```

So what I am trying to do is if end-user enter Test123 the system will calculate that the  EndDate would be (for example 11/08/2016) when the StartDate would be (for example 11/05/2016). Bearing mind before entering Testing123 the orginal EndDate has already been stored, for example 10/10/2016.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

**Edit**

I also continuing searching and found the following link

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932947/sql-server-2005-how-to-subtract-6-month)

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want the calculated date to be 3 months from the StartDate, or from the current date?

Comment: @UberDoodles - yes please. So regardless what the orginal EndDate is the calculation will be done from the StartDate, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, I think you need something like this.

```
Declare 
@StartDate DateTime,
@EndDate DateTime,
@Discount Varchar

If @Discount = 'Test123'
Begin
 UPDATE tblName 
 SET EndDate = case 
  When StartDate > dateadd(month,-3,getdate())
   Then dateadd(month,3,StartDate)
 end
End
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. I am unable to try this right now will try this tomorrow.